# What is the most performant and reliable algorithm to find all roots of a nonlinear function within a range?

Tags: numerical-algorithms, performance

Following [this question](https://discordapp.com/channels/384316553497280512/754701275735654410/920147816179982367) on MATLAB's Discord channel, I did a bit of search and found [this interesting answer](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/143643-fzero-function-calculating-all-zeros-within-interval#comment_736113) using `circshift()` function to detect zero-crossings. I used the answer to provide [this answer](https://discordapp.com/channels/384316553497280512/754701275735654410/920265012143087616):

```matlab
x = linspace(-10, 10, 200);
f=@(x) exp(x) - x.^4 .* sin(x) - 100

zx = f(x) .* circshift(f(x), [-1]) <= 0;  % Estimate zero crossings
zx = zx(1:end-1); % Eliminate any due to ‘wrap-around’ effect
zx = x(zx);

for k1 = 1:length(zx)
    fz(k1) = fzero(f, zx(k1));
end

fz

fplot(f, [-10, 10]);
```

but the question triggered me to think if there is a performant and reliable algorithm to find all the zeroes of a nonlinear function within a range? The approach I can think of uses random initial point selection and a recursive method. See the below pseudocode assuming we have a `find_zero` function that finds a random root within that interval efficiently (but not reliably):

```
# python-like pseudocode 

function find_all_roots(input_function, interval[start, end]): # srat < end
    first_root = find_root(input_function, interval[start, end])
    
    if first_root is None:
        roots_array = empty_array
    else
        roots_array = concatenate _arrays(\\
            find_all_roots(input_function, interval[start, first_root]), \\
            [first_root], \\
            find_all_roots(input_function, interval[first_root, end]))

    return roots_array
```

Now the questions are:

- Is this algorithm the most performant one or there are better possibilities?
- Does this algorithm guarantee to find all roots?
- What if the imaginary `find_zero()` function fails to find a zero? Either because there is none, or the numerical method fails to converge. How to handle that to achieve the best performance and reliability?

You don't have to provide me with actual code, as pseudocode is also fine for me. But Python or MATLAB/Octave implementation would be highly appreciated.

Comment: "performant and reliable" - please tell us more about what you mean by that.  Depending on the function you are trying to find the zeros of, it might be arbitrarily hard (might take arbitrarily long).  There are *many* methods for finding roots of nonlinear functions; what research have you done and which approaches have you identified so far?  What are you assuming is known about the function?  That we can calculate its value at any given point?  Can we do the same for its derivatives, second-order derivatives, etc.?  Is it a function of one variable or many variables?

Comment: Coding questions and Matlab/Octave/Python code are off-topic here.

Comment: What's the difference between "reliably" vs "not reliably"?  If find_zero is not reliable, then I don't understand how it is helpful -- it might always return "failed".  Or, to put it another way, how should we analyze the performance/quality of an algorithm that uses find_zero?  We presumably can't use worst-case running time, as the worst case is that find_zero always returns "failed".

Comment: @D.W. I have not asked a MATLAB/Octave/Python question. I have just used the MATLAB code as an example of one algorithm that works. And have expressed my preference if, and only if, people what to code it down.

Comment: I have used the term "reliable" for the `find_zero` as if there is a root, the function should find it. And for the `find_all_roots` reliable means it should find all of them.

Comment: OK, but I'm afraid my concerns or questions remain, and most of them remain unanswered.  I don't find the problem well-posed in its current form, for the reasons articulated above.

Comment: @D.W. can you be kind to elaborate on your questions and concerns? I'm not as well educated on the topic as you are. There are many things that I don't know that I don't know. Hence asking a question here.

Comment: 1. Do you want this only for a function of a single variable, or a function of multiple variables?  (e.g., f(x)=x^3 vs f(x,y)=x^3+y^3)  2. What is given to the algorithm?  Are we given a black box that, on input x, returns f(x)?  Are we given a way to also evaluate the derivatives of the function?  This will determine which methods can be used.  3. It is unclear why "find_root" is of any use at all if it is not reliable, so it's not clear why you are asking us to use it.

Comment: 4. How do you plan to measure "performant"?  How will you evaluate answers?  We are a question-and-answer platform, and to make questions work well here, we need clearly specified criteria/metrics/requirements that can be used to evaluate answers.  It is unclear what you mean by "performant".  The standard approach in computer science is to measure performance by worst-case asymptotic running time, but that is not appropriate here for a number of reasons articulated above, so you will need to define precisely how it should be measured, or give us a concrete practical situation.

Comment: 5. There are *many* methods for finding roots.  We expect you to [do a significant amount of research before asking here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/781723), and to summarize what you've found so far, which ones you've rejected and why, and use that to refine your question and articulate your requirements clearly.  A search on Wikipedia immediately turns up [an article on many methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithms), which makes me suspect you haven't done enough research yet; and in any case, those are natural candidates for answers.

Comment: 1. it is a single variable function <br/> 2. it is a black-box function but we can numerically calculate df/dx <br/> 3. If it is a misleading or wrong assumption, you may expand the answer and provide a "reliable" algorithm for `find_zero` function as well, or take a completely different approach.

Comment: 4. I was hoping performance already has some metrics in the field of computer science. Aren't there ways to compare algorithms performance-wise, regardless of hardware, operating system, and/or programming languages?

Comment: 4. As I've already mentioned, the standard metric for algorithm performance (worst-case asymptotic running time) is not applicable here, for a number of reasons.  I suggest reading about root-finding algorithms -- that will help you understand more about how these are evaluated -- and also thinking about how you would evaluate answers that are posted here.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include all relevant information into the question.  We don't want people to have to read the comments to get this information.  Don't just append "edit: more stuff added", but revise the question so it reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time.  Then you can flag obsolete comments as 'no longer needed'  Thank you!

Comment: 2. What about second derivatives, third derivatives, etc.?  By "numerically calculate" do you mean using [finite differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation#Finite_differences) or do you have a way to directly compute the derivative?

Comment: 3. It seems to me like trying to boost an unreliable method into a reliable method is a separable concern from boosting a method to find one root into one that finds all roots.  Also, the root-finding methods that I am familiar with are all reliable (I think?), so I am not clear on what is the motivation for assuming our root-finding method is unreliable.  If it is unreliable, my first thought would be to replace it with one that is reliable.  So it might help to explain your motivation here and why you have formulated the problem in this way.